# Determine the critical region for this test at significance level $\alpha = 0.05$.

Tags: statistics

Let the random variable $X$ be the waiting time until the next student has to go to the toilet. Assume that $X$ has an $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution with unknown $\lambda$. We test $H_0 :\lambda= 0.2$ against $H_1 :\lambda < 0.2$, where we use $X$ as test statistic. Determine the critical region for this test at significance level $\alpha = 0.05$.

In my opinion I should calculate $P(X<C)|H_0)=1-e^{-\lambda x}=1-e^{-0.2x}$. So $1-e^{-0.2x}=0.05$, so $x=0.25$ and the critical region is $(-\infty,0.25]$, is it the right method to solve this question?

Comment: Confusing notation here. You say $X\sim Exp(X)$ with unknown $A$ then immediately start talking about $\lambda$. Surely you mean $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$ where $\mathbb{E}(X)=1/\lambda$ and $\lambda$ is the unknown parameter you want to test on.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 sorry, you are right, it is $Exp(\lambda)$, corrected :)

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown A"? What is A? And what is the sample size?

Comment: @callculus I think that it's time that I learn how to write on latex, sorry guys, it should be a $\lambda$.

Comment: And the sample size is what, equal to 1?

Comment: @callculus is not given, so I think that we can assume that is 1.

Comment: @MarkJacon The equation is $1−e^{−0.2x}=0.05$ Note the negative sign at the exponent. Then the critical region is $(−\infty,0.2565)$

Comment: @callculus oh yes I forgot to type the minus but I put in the calculator, thanks!

Comment: @MarkJacon You´re welcome.

Comment: Attempt to clairfy: You seem to have only a single observation $X$ to test this hypothesis. Clearly, you want to reject when $X$ is small. In particular you want  $P(X < c|\lambda = .2) = 0.05.$ In R statistical software you can find $c = 0.2565$ using code `qexp(.05,.2)`, which returns 0.2564665, and confirm using code `pexp(.2565, .2)`, which returns 0.05000637. In R, `pexp` is an exponential CDF and `qexp` is the quantile function (inverse CDF). For this simple problem you don't need software, but it is good to have the framework in mind.

Comment: @BruceET thanks for this insight, also because I have to start using R next week :)
So for this example should I use the exponential or the quantile function?

Comment: The quantile function of the exponential distribution. Compare what I did with `qexp` and what @callculus did with $1−e^{−0.2x}=0.05$ to get  0.2565. // Wishing you success with R. (At each stage learn just what you need for the task at hand. Don't try to learn 'all of R').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, any region $R\subset \mathbb R$ such that
$$P_{\lambda=0.2}(X\in R)=0.05$$
is a correct answer, in theory. But some of these answers would be absurd in practice.

Since the alternative hypothesis is that $\lambda<0.2$, and since this is equivalent to say that $E(X)>\frac1{0.2}=5$, we see that it is only reasonable to reject $H_0$ when $X$ takes values sensibly greater than $5$. That is, the critical region should be
$$(C,\infty)$$
for $C\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$P(X\in (C,\infty))=P(X>C)=1-(1-e^{-0.2C})=e^{-0.2C}=0.05.$$

So $C=-5\ln(0.05)\approx 14.98$ and the critical region is $$(14.98,+\infty).$$

Comment: why you assume the $E(X)$ and not the value of \lambda? The critical region should not be the area where we reject $H_0$ in favour of $H_1$, so where $\lambda<0.2$?

Comment: By definition, the critical region is any region $R$ such that $$P(X\in R)=\alpha$$ if $H_0$ is true. So both mine or your answer can be technically right. But for the test to make sense in practice (or, more rigorously, to have good properties, like so-called unbiasedness), you have to build $R$ using those values which are more likely to occur if $H_1$ is true. And the case is that the smaller $\lambda$ is, the greater the values of $X$ expected. This is the case for the exponential distribution, and that's why it is reasonable a critical region that contains big, not small, values.

Comment: I mean, let's assume that $H_0$ is false, because actually $\lambda=0.0001$. The expected value of $X$ would be $10,000$, so you want to choose a critical region that includes the greatest values. If you chose a critical region such as $(0,0.25)$ or so, it is almost sure that you will fail to reject $H_0$ (because those values are most likely not going to occur, given that $E(X)=10,000$), even when it is really obvious that $\lambda$ is much smaller than what is assumed in $H_0$. That is, $H_0$ is evidently false, but the test would say that you have to keep this absurd hypothesis.